# PHP Публикация данных с фильтром по дате добавления в БД

Tags: sqlite, запрос, select

Други, подскажите чайнику, как мне добавить это

```
WHERE $created_at > datetime('now','-1 day')
```

Вот сюда:

```
function property_list($where=FALSE){
    $db = db();
    return $db->query("SELECT * FROM property ".($where?'WHERE '.$where:'').' ORDER BY `created_at` DESC',PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

В общем, задача в том, чтобы эта функция выбирала не все из БД (sqlite), а только за последние сутки.

А то мои собственные попытки приводят к слому дизайна, отображению пустой страницы и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

prepare() - подготавливаем запрос, execute() - запускаем запрос на выполнение с передачей параметров которые будут подставлены вместо ? в запросе, fetchAll() - возвращаем результат в виде массива.

```
function property_list($date){
    $conn = new PDO('sqlite:my_database.sqlite3');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM property WHERE created_at = ? ORDER BY `created_at` DESC";
    $result = $conn->prepare($query);
    $result->execute($date);
    return $result->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Напишу, что получится. Только завтра, наверное. Сегодня мозг сломан уже

Comment: Пробуйте, так же роль играет в каком формате сохранена дата в бд)

Comment: Дата в структуре БД - DATETIME.